# POST request to PHP from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variables, post, submit

I basically want to submit a variable to the same page (index.php) so I can use it in my PHP. If i submit this it works fine, but I want to use a variable instead of an input element, as well as this firing on page load, so ideally all in javascript. Im new to GET and POST ajax in Javascript and haven't been able to do it using that. Can anyone help me with writing what I want to do in Javascript/jQuery?

HTML at the moment:

```
 <form method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="myInput" id="name="myInput">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
 $answer = $_POST['myInput'];
 echo $answer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick answer to your question using jQuery:

```
$.post( "index.php", { myInput: "myValue", myOtherInput: "myOtherValue" } );
```

Since you are posting to the same page, you can omit the `url` value:

```
$.post( "", { myInput: "myValue", myOtherInput: "myOtherValue" } );
```

However, this method uses AJAX and will not preform a full-page postback (the page will not reload).

If a postback is what is required (as when submitting a regular `<form>`, then you can do this:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var input = $("<input>")
               .attr("type", "hidden")
               .attr("name", "myOtherInput").val("myOtherValue");
    $(this).append(input);
    return true;
});
```

That code will intercept the form `submit` event and add another `<input>` with the name `myOtherInput` and the value `myOtherValue`.

You can access it in the same way you access `myValue` in your post:

```
$myValue = $_POST['myValue'];
$myOtherValue = $_POST['myOtherValue'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe i need to use the a way that reloads the page like a form would as to be usable in the PHP. I dont really understand what you've done though. I want to eliminate using a html form so on page load, it essentially does what a physical form would do, and use it to send a variable value. name = 'john' for example. Thanks.

Comment: Well, first of all you don't need a full-page postback for the variable to be usable in PHP. But assuming that you do need a full-page postback for some other reason, you would need  a `<form>` element. You're going to have a `submit` button right? Well, put a form element around it.

Comment: No, I was wanting it to fire on page load. Ive got it working now as a form and setting my value as a hidden input element and submitting it with javascript on page load, but because it essentially reloads and then fires the onsubmit again its just looping constantly. Any way around that? I did  document.forms['myForm'].submit()

Comment: Why would you want it to fire on page load? That doesn't make much sense. The only way around that is to have your `PHP` script include the javascript into the page only when `$_POST['myValue']` is not set.

Comment: my index is a php file that grabs some values from a database and i'm wanting to do it so the grab them according to this javascript variable. So if i post this first to the PHP it can then run the query using the variable. Probably completely backwards but i'm pretty new to PHP.

Comment: You want to grab them according to the javascript variable, but you're setting the javascript variable on the page `onload` event? What information can this variable provide that you don't already know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75611/discussion-between-mikhail-furlender-and-jord49).

Answer (score 0):

Should have made a post to the PHP when clicking to enter the current page, rather than trying to grab it onload. This helped me fix the problem.